# Validation of parameter - web api 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WEB API 2.0 in my project.
I have some controller with dozen of action methods.
Each action method get object that inherit from `BaseRequest`

```
[DataContract]
Public class BaseRquest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string playerId {get;set;}
}
```

In each method I have code that validate if player with `PlayerId` exists in DB , if so it pass to BL layer the `Player` object and if no it return `Nofound` response.

I want to delete this duplicate code of validation in all action methods and write it at one place in the code. 
Remember that if the validation success I need to pass `Player` to BL layer.

How can I do this and yet to delete the duplication of validation in each action methods?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a Filter. https://damienbod.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/

Comment: @lcryder How Do I pass the Player object to controller action method atfter the validation in filter?

Comment: The inbound message would be accessible in the HttpContext object. The filter would deserialize the message into an object.